# How to spread players that are in a certain area

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a server where I want to spread the players in the lobby A to Area A without it affecting the players in Lobby B or C. I hope that makes since. This is in Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

I tried:

```
/spreadplayers -96 -4 0 30 @a[x=-21,y=0,r=10]
```

But even when I have someone in that area it says "No targets matched selector".

Comment: y=0? Your players are at the bottom of the world?

Comment: You might also need `z=`.

Answer (score 1):

After typing `/spreadplayers` in chat to examine its parameters, here is a functioning command:

```
/spreadplayers <x value> <z value> <spread distance> <max distance> <victime/targetSelector>
```

*on a side note: `spread distance` is how far apart the players should be from each other.*

Answer (score -1):

You have to make Lobby A far enough away from Lobby B and C so that the command block doesn't affect it. I am also pretty sure you need to add @a

Comment: Why do you need to add `@a`?

Comment: Because you need a target. @a is the target option you need